# Type error: Generic type is not assignable

Tags: typescript

The following code generates an type error, that I'm unable to understand. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
Type '(state: State) => State' is not assignable to type 'Action'.
  Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
    Type 'S' is not assignable to type 'State'.
```

The error is generated on line 14 (`const action: Action = ...`).

```
interface IState {
  count: number;
}

class State implements IState {
  count: number;
}

type Action = <S>(state: S) => S
type Dispatch = <A extends Action>(action: A) => void

const dispatch = (action: Action) => { }

const action: Action = (state: State) => state

dispatch(action)
```

I expect for `State` and the generic type `S` to be compatible.

[TS playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IState%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20count%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20State%20implements%20IState%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20count%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atype%20Action%20%3D%20%3CS%3E(state%3A%20S)%20%3D%3E%20S%0Atype%20Dispatch%20%3D%20%3CA%20extends%20Action%3E(action%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20void%0A%0Aconst%20dispatch%20%3D%20(action%3A%20Action)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0A%0Aconst%20action%3A%20Action%20%3D%20(state%3A%20State)%20%3D%3E%20state%0A%0Adispatch(action))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Action` represents a generic function. A generic function implies it can be called with *any* type that satisfies the type constrained for a given type parameter.

So this code compiles without any issues:

```
declare const action: Action;
action({ count: 0 }); //should return  {count :number } 
action({ sum: 0 });//should return  {sum :number } 
action({ msg: "Some text" });//should return  {msg:number }
```

The problem is that your function (at least according to it's signature) does not satisfy this requirement. It takes in a state and returns a state. As highlighted above the requirements of `action` make it more flexible.

If your function is truly just an identity function you can just use `any` to make the function compatible with the signature

```
const action: Action = (state: any) => state
```

Or you can make the function implementation generic:

```
const action: Action = <T>(state: T) => state
```

If what you want is not a generic function (ie a function that works for any `T`) but a regular function with a signature that can be customized for a given type, you need to put the type argument on `Action`:

```
type Action<S> = (state: S) => S
type Dispatch = <A extends Action<any>>(action: A) => void

const dispatch = (action: Action<any>) => { }

const action: Action<IState> = (state) => state
    //declare const action: Action;
action({ count: 0 });
action({ sum: 0 }); // error
action({ msg: "Some text" }); // error


dispatch(action)
```